# ListView getChildAt(i) gives null

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with with custom Layout. ListView items come from a separate xml document. The listview renders properly, now I want to access the textview and the editview which is in that listview, and I want to change the value of that dynamically. I tried it using `list.getChildAt(i)` but it gives me a null view. So how can I access the textviews?

```
ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); 
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this,5,R.layout.layout_id); 
list.setAdapter(adapter); 
for (int j = 0; j < list.getCount(); j++) { 
    View v = list.getChildAt(j);
    EditText text = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    text.setText("Hello");
}
```

---

Ok I tried a lot and found that list.getChildAt(i) gives me value on onClickListener(). I want to get that value after the list render in onCreate() method. So how can i get the list value immediately of list render?

Comment: please show some code...

Comment: likely if the view is not visible. change the values in you adapter, not directly on the views

Comment: please provide some code of yours

Comment: ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
 adapter=new LazyAdapter(this,5,R.layout.layout_id);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
           
 for (int j = 0; j < list.getCount(); j++) 
 {
   View v =  list.getChildAt(j);
            
   EditText text = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
   text.setText("Hello");
         
 }

Comment: Please add code as an edit to your Post.

Comment: what about the code of `LazyAdapter`?

Comment: The `getChildAt` method, when used with a `ListView` will return a non-null value only for the rows that are visible on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you used a custom Layout, did you write your own Adapter? If so, you properly have to override the `getChildAt`-method. Hence you have to manage the model on your own.